# Obtaining vegetation data for a coordinate location (lat/long) using ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, buffer, arcgis-10.4, latitude-longitude

I have location coordinates (lat/long) for a province in Canada and I want to map the type of vegetation to that location. I am trying to extract the vegetation data from land cover files which are in .tif format.

To do this should it be a point query, or does creating a buffer around the coordinate and then taking some weighted average value makes more sense?

Comment: Hello Anwer, welcome to GIS Stackexchange. As it stands, it's not quite clear what your issue is. Please *edit your question* to include more information about the data you're working with. Do you already have a layer with information about vegetation? If so, what format is it in?

Comment: Hello, yes I do have a layer and it is in .tif format. I have weather records for several locations (lat/long) and now I want to map the vegetation type to each record.

Comment: @csk I also have a legend for vegetation types. So if I can extract the vegetation value I would know the vegetation type.